# Keras CNN - always predicting the same class in a balanced dataset, but the accuracy is high - why?

Tags: python, keras

I am facing with the following problem, for which I firstly want to give you the code and then explain it in detail:

```
#Just try to implement the modular
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy
from numpy import newaxis

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("example.csv", delimiter = ",")
X = dataset[:, 0:200]
Y = dataset[:, 200]
s1 = X.shape[0]
s2 = X.shape[1]
newshape = (s1, s2, 1)
X = numpy.reshape(X, newshape)
#print(X.shape[2])
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(16, 3, border_mode = "same", input_shape = (200, 1)))
#model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=200, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length = 2))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, border_mode = "same"))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, border_mode = "same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length = 2))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, border_mode = "same", activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, border_mode = "same", activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
print("here1")

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = sgd, metrics = ['accuracy'] )
print('here2')
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 64, nb_epoch = 1)
#print("here3")
#scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose = 0)
print(score)
output = model.predict(X, batch_size = 20,  verbose = 0)
print(output[0:100])
#print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
#scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
```

What I am doing is the following: As an input (X), I feed the network DNA code (coded as numbers), the label (Y) is binary (either 0 or 1). I want to predict Y. When I run the model, it behaves very strangely, at least in a way I cannot understand:

[image]

Now to picture, here is my question: On the predicted labels output (result of the line
    print(output[0:100])
)
the model is always predicting a 0. However, the accuracy, as given above is seemingly very high. Why is that? Mind that the dataset is balanced, meaning half of the observations are labeled 1, half of them 0. So predicting all the values with 0 should result in an accuracy rate of 0.5 .

Edit:

As I was asked for the data, here is a screenshot from it. The last number of each line is the label.

[image]

Comment: perhaps there is something wrong in your parsed input data, just add the data to your question?

Comment: ok, I added an extract from the data.

Comment: I believe it might be a problem with the input_shape, since actually I don't really understand what to put in there and just tried to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! In general it is better to add the data as text and not as an image so people can copy&paste it. If your data is DNA, i.e. 4 different bases, if is preferable to use 4 binary inputs instead of 1 linear input. There is no reason why A should be 1 and T 4 or any other arbitrary number.

Comment: Ok, I will use this recommendation for my future posts and try to adjust the input type as you mentioned. Still, I think for the described problem above this would not make any difference.

Comment: Anyone with a small idea what I could try? I feel really lost right know, since it seems to be a problem in the internals of Keras which I don't really understand.

Comment: Can you check what is the Keras configuration in ~/.keras/keras.json ?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean? Is this in python or is this a file somewhere on my disk? I couldnt find the file.

Comment: Try using a simple input like 200 zeros and a single 1 in each different location, output is always 1. 200 zeros with two or more 1s in different locations, output is always 0. This should give you a quick idea if your network is correct.

Comment: I tried to follow your pattern, Max. But from this kind of testing, I dont really get any step further... I think there is some fundamental problem in the problem I wrote above, but I really cant figure it out..

Comment: Can you also show some samples with label of 0?

Comment: The most obvious answer is that all the Y inputs are zero due to some bug. As a sanity check, can you try printing Y (the input values you are training on)? Ideally print the number of 1s and zeros in Y

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data are not properly scaled. As a debug step, you can use **linear** activation function on last layer and see the result.